# List of Figures, Subfloats and Here are causing weird assigning in LOF

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, subfloats

I try to integrate subfloats in my `.tex` file the way they're listed under the corresponding figure-scope. Unfortunately, when using here i.e `[H]` to place my figure where I want it, `\listoffigures` is listing the subfloat captions under a wrong figure. Here is a demo script, in which this is happening. When removing `[H]` the subfloat captions are assigned correctly. Has somebody an idea to get this working correctly with `[H]`? I'm looking forward to some answers!

Best,
TheOrangeman

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth=2]{subfig}
\usepackage{here}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{File 1}
\caption{File 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[File A]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{FileA}} \qquad
\subfloat[File B]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{FileB}} \\
\subfloat[File C]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{FileC}} \qquad
\subfloat[File D]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{FileD}}
\caption[LOF Caption]{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{File 2}
\caption{File 2}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

EDIT : 
[image: My Output of pdfLatex]

EDIT2 :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.10.15)  16 JAN 2017 17:44
entering extended mode
**demo.tex
(demo.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfig\subfig.sty"
Package: subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
Package: caption 2015/09/17 v3.3-111 Customizing captions (AR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"
Package: caption3 2015/09/20 v1.7-115 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 57.
\captionmargin=\dimen105
\captionmargin@=\dimen106
\captionwidth=\dimen107
\caption@tempdima=\dimen108
\caption@indent=\dimen109
\caption@parindent=\dimen110
\caption@hangindent=\dimen111
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count88
)
\c@KVtest=\count89
\sf@farskip=\skip43
\sf@captopadj=\dimen112
\sf@capskip=\skip44
\sf@nearskip=\skip45
\c@subfigure=\count90
\c@subfigure@save=\count91
\c@lofdepth=\count92
\c@subtable=\count93
\c@subtable@save=\count94
\c@lotdepth=\count95
\sf@top=\skip46
\sf@bottom=\skip47
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\here.sty") (demo.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count96
\scratchdimen=\dimen113
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count97
\nofMParguments=\count98
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count99
\MPscratchDim=\dimen114
\MPnumerator=\count100
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count101
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
34.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: subfig package v1.3 is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
 [1{C:/Users/Felix/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

] (demo.lof
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 1.
)
\tf@lof=\write3
 [2]
(demo.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  subfig.sty    2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package
 caption.sty    2015/09/17 v3.3-111 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2015/09/20 v1.7-115 caption3 kernel (AR)
    here.sty    
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2699 strings out of 493673
 42584 string characters out of 3143959
 102537 words of memory out of 3000000
 6044 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6982 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,9n,47p,247b,304s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on demo.pdf (2 pages, 35501 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 21 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

EDIT3:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.16)  16 JAN 2017 18:13
entering extended mode
**./demo.tex
(demo.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 72 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfig\subfig.sty"
Package: subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
Package: caption 2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"
Package: caption3 2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 67.
\captionmargin=\dimen105
\captionmargin@=\dimen106
\captionwidth=\dimen107
\caption@tempdima=\dimen108
\caption@indent=\dimen109
\caption@parindent=\dimen110
\caption@hangindent=\dimen111
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count88
)
\c@KVtest=\count89
\sf@farskip=\skip43
\sf@captopadj=\dimen112
\sf@capskip=\skip44
\sf@nearskip=\skip45
\c@subfigure=\count90
\c@subfigure@save=\count91
\c@lofdepth=\count92
\c@subtable=\count93
\c@subtable@save=\count94
\c@lotdepth=\count95
\sf@top=\skip46
\sf@bottom=\skip47
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\here.sty") (demo.aux)
\openout1 = `demo.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count96
\scratchdimen=\dimen113
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count97
\nofMParguments=\count98
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count99
\MPscratchDim=\dimen114
\MPnumerator=\count100
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count101
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: subfig package v1.3 is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
 [1{C:/Users/SG11B/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

] (demo.lof
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 1.
 [2])
\tf@lof=\write3
\openout3 = `demo.lof'.


[3] (demo.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  subfig.sty    2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
    here.sty    
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2714 strings out of 493366
 42888 string characters out of 3139856
 102971 words of memory out of 3000000
 6228 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6982 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1127 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,9n,49p,249b,304s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on demo.pdf (3 pages, 35929 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 24 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

EDIT4:

```
%%%  @LaTeX-style-file{
%%%     filename        = "here.sty",
%%%     version         = "1.01",
%%%     date            = "12 June 1992",
%%%     time            = "15:26:24 BST",
%%%     author          = "David Carlisle",
%%%     address         = "Computer Science Department
%%%                        Manchester University
%%%                        Oxford Road
%%%                        Manchester
%%%                        England
%%%                        M13 9PL",
%%%     telephone       = "+44 61 275 6139",
%%%     FAX             = "+44 61 275 6236",
%%%     checksum        = "51873 214 1175 8528",
%%%     email           = "carlisle@cs.man.ac.uk (Internet)",
%%%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",
%%%     keywords        = "LaTeX, figure, table, floats",
%%%     supported       = "yes",
%%%     docstring       = "
%%%
%%%     here.sty
%%%
%%%     A LaTeX style option giving floats a [H] option,
%%%     meaning `do not float', or `PUT IT HERE'.
%%%
%%%     Documentation requires Mittelbach's doc.sty.
%%%
%%%     The checksum field above was produced by
%%%     Robert Solovay's checksum utility.",
%%%  }
%%% ====================================================================
\ifx\@Hxfloat\@Hundef\else\expandafter\endinput\fi
\let\@Hxfloat\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat#1[{\@ifnextchar{H}{\@HHfloat{#1}[}{\@Hxfloat{#1}[}}
\def\@HHfloat#1[H]{%
\expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\end@Hfloat
\vskip\intextsep\vbox\bgroup\def\@captype{#1}\parindent\z@
\ignorespaces}
\def\end@Hfloat{\egroup\vskip \intextsep}

\endinput
%% 
%% End of file `here.sty'.
```

Comment: I see the captions in the specified order, especially A, B, C, D belong to figure `2` as specified

Comment: I see A, B, C, D assigned to the figure with caption 'File 2', which is the third figure in the tex-File. Can you confirm this?

Comment: No.... It says LoF Caption, A, B,C,D in this order, the caption of File 2 is the last one

Comment: I edited the main post and added a picture of my output, I'm using Texmaker 4.4.1 with MiKTex 2.9 and compiling it with pdfLatex if this information helps. Experiencing the same problem on my notebook.

Comment: See the output on my machine (TL 2016, daily updated, Linux): http://imgur.com/a/sxR0P

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post the result of the output. I think the key to solve the problem is an update of `caption` package.

Comment: I added the log with \listfiles to the main post. I'll update the environment and I'll report of the result.

Comment: Most of the packages have a new version, compared to your local configuration

Comment: I updated the miktex environment completly. Running pdfLatex results in the same List of Figures, I also deleted the old *.lof file and executed it again. Same result :(.

Comment: There's no difference now to my `\listfiles` output.

Comment: I just found out that when I use `\usepackage{float}` instead of `\usepackage{here}` for `[H]`, the List of figures is correct.. computers are evil machines... I don't get it. Anyway it works now. Thanks again for your effort Christian.

Comment: Well, `here` is just `\RequirePackage{float}`  -- it should load `float` automatically. I wondered already why you used that old stuff ...

Comment: Please look into `here.sty` whether it is really using `\RequirePackage{float}`

Comment: Out of curiosity I looked intro `here.sty`and you were right. As far as I understand, `float` isn't loaded, right? See main post for `here.sty` (edit4).

Comment: @TheOrangeman: You have an incorrect `here.sty`. [This is what `here.sty` should look like](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/here/here.sty) (from CTAN). Remove it from your repository and re-install it. It should be in `~/tex/latex/here`, not `~/tex/latex/ltxmisc`. Did you put it there?

Comment: Nope! It was like when I installed MiKTeX. Just checked it with a reinstallation. But good to know that something's not right there. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Werner Would you like to answer, or close as OT due to buggy installation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems related to a faulty `here.sty`.